# Update multiple documents in MongoDB at once

Tags: mongodb

Currently I work with MongoDB 4.0. I can insert multiple documents at once like this:

```
db.books.insertMany([
  {
    "_id" : 1,
    "item" : "TBD",
    "stock" : 0,
    "info" : { "publisher" : "1111", "pages" : 430 },
    "tags" : [ "technology", "computer" ],
    "ratings" : [ { "by" : "ijk", "rating" : 4 }, { "by" : "lmn", "rating" : 5 } ],
    "reorder" : false
   },
   {
    "_id" : 2,
    "item" : "XYZ123",
    "stock" : 15,
    "info" : { "publisher" : "5555", "pages" : 150 },
    "tags" : [ ],
    "ratings" : [ { "by" : "xyz", "rating" : 5 } ],
    "reorder" : false
   }
]);
```

The problem is when I want to update stock of first item to 5 and stock of second item to 10, can I update multiple documents at once like in `insertMany`? If yes, how to do that?

Comment: Yes, there is `updateMany` available.

Comment: How to do that? I want to make condition like: if _id = 1 set stock = 5 and if _id = 2 set stock = 10. I see that we can update all fields if we want to update a document. But how if I want to update multiple documents at once?

Answer (score 0):

You should try the `bulkWrite` operation in mongodb

```
try {
   db.books.bulkWrite(
      [

         { updateOne :
            {
               "filter" : { "_id" : 1 },
               "update" : { $set : { "stock " : 5} }
            }
         },
         { updateOne :
            {
               "filter" : { "_id" : 2 },
               "update" : { $set : { "stock " : 10} }
            }
         }
      ]
   );
}
catch (e) {
   print(e);
}
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/bulk-write-operations/